# How do I validate a single JSON object against my schema containing all definitions?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I built my JSON schema in pieces, one schema per object I need to validate, and tested each component before moving on to the next. Individually, they all work as designed.

Next, I pasted all the schemas into one big schema file and tried to validate one of test objects against it. It passed but should have failed. It appears none of the schemas are being applied and everything is passing. Specifically, in the schema snippet included below, my object has a `DataInterfaceID` of `-1` but it still passes validation. Evertyhing worked until I merged the individual schemas into one file.

This is the schema, trimmed down to the minimum necessary to reproduce the issue:

```
{
    '$schema': 'http: //json-schema.org/draft-04/schema',
    'type': 'object',
    'id': 'http: //sampleURI/',
    'required': false,
    'properties': {
        'EquipmentSchedule': {
            'title': 'EquipmentSchedule',
            'required': false,
            'description': 'EquipmentSchedule',
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {
                'DataInterfaceID': {
                    'type': 'integer',
                    'minimum': 1,
                    'required': true
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even if required elements are missing, the validation passes. Why is this not working and how do I resolve the issue? Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to validate? Strictly speaking, your schema is invalid according to DRAFT 4, since `required`, as a validation keyword for objects... `The value of this keyword MUST be an array. This array MUST have at least one element. Elements of this array MUST be strings, and MUST be unique.` With that aside, in my case `{"EquipmentSchedule" : { "DataInterfaceID" : 0}}` fails as expected `Integer 0 is less than minimum value of 1. Line 1, position 46. Document1.json`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is a late response, but the DRAFT 4 requirements would be implemented as follows:

```
{
    "$schema": "http: //json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "id": "http: //sampleURI/",
    "properties": {
        "EquipmentSchedule": {
            "title": "EquipmentSchedule",
            "description": "EquipmentSchedule",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "DataInterfaceID": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "minimum": 1
                }
            },
            "required": [ "DataInterfaceID" ]
        }
    }
}
```

Petru explained the reasoning best, but I decided to show you what an example would look like.